# Is Mark Zuckerberg subject to questioning by every U.S. senator, or only select ones?

Tags: regulations, antitrust-law, us-senate

I have been watching the live questioning for the last 2-3 hours and wonder about the Senate's hearing process: Do all of the senators get to question Mark, or just a limited number of them?  And if the number is limited, how are the senators chosen?

(From some of the questions, it feels like some senators don't even know what Facebook is.)

Comment: If you mean "All the Senators in the US Senate, then the answer is no. He's in front of a a subcommittee. The Senate has many, and not all senators are on all subcommittees.

Answer (score 2):

He appeared at a joint meeting of the Senate [Judiciary](https://www.judiciary.senate.gov/about/members) and [Commerce](https://www.commerce.senate.gov/public/index.cfm/committeemembers) Committees, so he was only questioned by the members of those committees, and even then, only the ones who showed up and chose to ask questions. You can follow the links to see who's on those committees.

Tomorrow he'll be appearing in front of the [House Energy and Commerce Committee](https://energycommerce.house.gov/about/).

Those are the committees that called him, so those are the committees whose members will get to question him. Unfortunately, you're right that most of these guys are completely clueless when it comes to the industries that they're trying to regulate.